# Sorting arrays using C

Tags: arrays, c, sorting

I'm trying to sort an array. The input is 34 15 3 56 41

When i = 0, j = 0, after sorting, the array is

A[0] = 15; A[1] = 34; A[2] = 3; A[3] = 56; A[4] = 41

where 15 & 34 swapped positions. However, after the second loop, when i = 0, j = 1, before any swaps, the array has been changed to

A[0] = 15; A[1] = 34; A[2] = 3; A[3] = 56; A[4] = 53

My question here is where did the A[4] = 53 come from when it should be A[4] = 41? Thanks in advance!

Here's my code:

```
/* takes in a list of numbers in an array and sort it */

#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void swap(int *p1, int *p2);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {  
    int n, i=0, j, A[i];        
    printf("Enter value of N: ");   
    scanf("%d", &n);        
    printf("Enter the numbers: ");  
    for (i=0; i<n; i++) {       
        scanf("%d", &A[i]);         
        printf("A[%d]  = %d\n", i, A[i]);   
    }           

    for (i=0; i<n; i++) {       
    printf("--- i = %d ---\n", i);      
        for (j=i+1; j<n; j+=1) {                
            printf("%d\n", j);          
            if (A[j]<A[i]) {
                printf("i = %d; j = %d\n", i, j);
                printf("A[0] = %d; A[1] = %d; A[2] = %d; A[3] = %d; A[4] = %d\n", A[0], A[1], A[2], A[3], A[4]);
                printf("Before: %d = %d; %d = %d\n", i, A[i], j, A[j]);
                swap(&A[i], &A[j]);
                printf("After: %d = %d; %d = %d\n", i, A[i], j, A[j]);
                printf("A[0] = %d; A[1] = %d; A[2] = %d; A[3] = %d; A[4] = %d\n", A[0], A[1], A[2], A[3], A[4]);
                printf("------\n");             
            }       
        }   
    }       
    return 0; 
}


 
void swap(int *p1, int *p2) {   
    int tmp;
    tmp = *p1;  
    *p1 = *p2;  
    *p2 = tmp; 
}
```

---

Here's the output:

```
Enter value of N: 5
Enter the numbers: 34 15 3 56 41
A[0]  = 34
A[1]  = 15
A[2]  = 3
A[3]  = 56
A[4]  = 41
--- i = 0 ---
1
i = 0; j = 1
A[0] = 34; A[1] = 15; A[2] = 3; A[3] = 56; A[4] = 41
Before: 0 = 34; 1 = 15
After: 0 = 15; 1 = 34
A[0] = 15; A[1] = 34; A[2] = 3; A[3] = 56; A[4] = 41
------
2
i = 0; j = 2
A[0] = 15; A[1] = 34; A[2] = 3; A[3] = 56; A[4] = 53
Before: 0 = 15; 2 = 3
After: 0 = 3; 2 = 15
A[0] = 3; A[1] = 34; A[2] = 15; A[3] = 56; A[4] = 53
------
3
4
--- i = 1 ---
2
i = 1; j = 2
A[0] = 3; A[1] = 34; A[2] = 15; A[3] = 56; A[4] = 53
Before: 1 = 34; 2 = 15
After: 1 = 15; 2 = 34
A[0] = 3; A[1] = 15; A[2] = 34; A[3] = 56; A[4] = 53
------
3
4
--- i = 2 ---
3
4
--- i = 3 ---
4
i = 3; j = 4
A[0] = 3; A[1] = 15; A[2] = 34; A[3] = 56; A[4] = 53
Before: 3 = 56; 4 = 53
After: 3 = 53; 4 = 56
A[0] = 3; A[1] = 15; A[2] = 34; A[3] = 53; A[4] = 56
------
--- i = 4 ---
```

Comment: [**We don't allow images of text (code/input/output/errors, or otherwise) on Stack Overflow**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). Please post all text into the question with [correct formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Questions with images of text/code/errors are routinely closed. Please also check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and the [question guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to make sure this & your future questions are suitable for this Q&A.

Comment: You expect us to tell you what is wrong with code you're not showing us? We read *code*, not minds. And I'm not going to sugarcoat it: It will tell us what you're doing far better than you could. [Update your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66038226/edit) with a proper [mcve] that we can copy, paste, compile, and run, using *only* the code you posted, and providing *only* the input you specify to achieve the erroneous results you claim, and we can almost guarantee finding the problem. Help us help *you*.

Comment: @WhozCraig

Hello, apologies for my mistake earlier, I was new to this and wasn't aware of the formatting of the post. I have updated my question with the code and output in the right formatting, appreciate it if you could help to answer my question. Thanks again!

Comment: @vanswhj, Your question is fine now that you fixed the image thing (that was not cool, but thank you for correcting it).  Whenever you see three people vote to close, but not a single downvote, you know it's just high-reputation users that forget what it was like to start coding and feel the need to flex their muscles by squashing the new guys.  Anyway, your bug is with `i=j+1`.  If `j` is already 4, then `i` becomes 5 and you are trying to do `A[5]` which is past the end of the bound of your array.  Hope this helps!  Sorry I couldn't make an answer.

Comment: @user1717828 The question was closed because images of code aren't acceptable. The question has been edited and I voted to reopen. Maybe you should vote to reopen instead of telling a new contributor the problem is that they're a "new guy". We vote on the post, not the person.